# How can I prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)(x^s+1)} dx=\frac{π}{2\sqrt{2a+2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Question:-** Prove that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)(x^s+1)} dx=\frac{π}{2\sqrt{2a+2}}$$

I Recenty got stuck on evaluating this integral,the result is independent of $s$. with $s=2$ , I verified the result.I don't know how to start evaluating the integral, since known method such as subsitution, Beta function(since it involves in these kind of problems) to me doesn't help here.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please add your work on what you claim to be your known method?

Comment: @amWhy I have now added what I think would be useful in problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let  $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{(x^4+2ax^2+1)(x^s+1)} dx$$

Start by substituting $x = 1/t$

$$\implies I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(t^4+2at^2+1)(1+\frac1{t^s})} dt$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(t^2+1)t^s}{(t^4+2at^2+1)(t^s+1)} dt$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(t^2+1)(t^s+1)-(t^2+1)}{(t^4+2at^2+1)(t^s+1)} dt$$
$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(t^4+2at^2+1)} dt - I$$
$$\implies 2I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2+1}{(t^4+2at^2+1)} dt$$

Now divide the numerator and denomintor by $t^2$
$$\implies 2I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{(t-\frac1t)^2+2a+2} dt$$

Now a simple substitution should do it.